# PHP - not getting same time in server and local

Tags: php

I need to get current Indian time from my server located in US-Texas.

I have stored time as UTC timestamp.
I am trying this way.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('O').'<br>';
echo date("F j, Y, h:i:s a", time()+(330*60)).'<br>';

I get correct time on my local server.
+0000
September 12, 2015, 10:59:53 am

and this on remote server.
+0000
September 12, 2015, 11:19:14 am
```

Please see and suggest why time is not same from remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()` function is returning GMT time. try to use `echo (new DateTime())->format('r');` instead

Comment: Using this i get this `Sat, 12 Sep 2015 06:10:26 +0000` on remote and this `Sat, 12 Sep 2015 05:51:05 +0000` on local, both are incorrect.

Comment: and what about `echo (new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Yekaterinburg'));)->format('r')` ?

Comment: on remote `Sat, 12 Sep 2015 11:27:41 +0500`, in local `Sat, 12 Sep 2015 12:08:20 +0600`

Comment: looks like some missconfiguration =( what timezone is set on your's local computer?

Comment: `(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi`

Comment: still, there is strange 20 minutes difference... did you tried to synchronize your's local computer time with some online time-provider service?

Comment: Shit, that was it. got it all right now. sorry my bad didn't see pc time is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly set your default time zone to `Asia/Calcutta`?

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Comment: Same result with this no change in time. Still getting incorrect time from server.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the time a strange offset to the time with the `+(330*60)` bit.  That is not the right way to do it.

Try

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta"); 
echo date("F j, Y, h:i:s a", time() ).'<br>';
```

Or Try

```
 ini_set( 'date.timezone', 'Asia/Calcutta' );
 echo date("F j, Y, h:i:s a", time() ).'<br>';
```

Comment: Using this there is no change in time, Same result as before

Comment: Still same result as before no change.

Comment: Add `print "PHP version => " . phpversion() . "<br>";`  and tell us what php version prints out

Comment: on remote `5.5.27` in local `5.5.12`

Comment: there is no reason then that `date_default_timezone_set` should not work. It seems like this is something you need to ask your hosts techsupport about.